# adding User acces/Permission for custome module

Tags: python, odoo

I have Created a simple module, It is just data form, I installed that module its working good, and I(Administrator) able to fill form. But when I tried to login from the other user, that installed module menu is not appearing in top menu bar. How can I give access to the User. Give me some idea about where to place the code, My sample Modules XML view is looks like follows.

and what is the use of following snippet in XML file.

```
<field name="help" type="html">
    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the first Question</p>
</field>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<openerp>
<data>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="course_list_action">
<field name="name">Questions form</field>
<field name="res_model">openacademy.course</field>
<field name="view_type">form</field>
<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    *<field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the first Question</p>
    </field>*
</record>       
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="course_form_view">
          <field name="name">course.form</field>
          <field name="model">openacademy.course</field>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <form string="Questions Form">
          <field name="name" colspan="4" />
          <field name="description" colspan="4" />
          <field name="date_of_q_created" colspan="4" />
          <field name="category_question" colspan="4" />
          <field name="create_uid" colspan="4" />
          </form>
          </field>
</record>

  <menuitem id="main_openacademy_menu" name="Manage forum" />
  <menuitem id="openacademy_menu" name="Discussion Forum" parent="main_openacademy_menu" />
  <menuitem id="courses_menu" name="Questions sidemenu" parent="openacademy_menu" action="course_list_action" />


</data>

</openerp>
```

Comment: Use groups in your xml or add permission as csv for example check sale module security/ir.model.access.csv

Answer (score 0):

sample ir.model.access.csv in sale/security

> id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
>   access_sale_shop,sale.shop,model_sale_shop,base.group_user,1,0,0,0
>   access_sale_order,sale.order,model_sale_order,base.group_sale_salesman,1,1,1,0
>   access_sale_order_line,sale.order.line,model_sale_order_line,base.group_sale_salesman,1,1,1,1

Create a csv file like this for your module and add groups

Add the specific user you wanted to have access to that module in the group